# GraphQL/Gatsby/Prismic - difference between 'edges.node.data' and 'nodes.data' in query

Tags: graphql, gatsby, prismic.io

I'm following [this](https://medium.com/source-group/start-a-new-website-with-gatsby-prismic-cms-netlify-a875455c992) tutorial on Medium to get Gatsby working with Prismic.

In the GraphiQL explorer, the two queries below both yield the same result and was wondering when I should use one over the other (i.e. **edges.node.data** vs **nodes.data**):

**Query #1:**

```
query Articles {
  articles: allPrismicArticle {
    edges {
      node {
        data {
          title {
            text
          }
          image {
            url
          }
          paragraph {
            html
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query #2:**

```
query Articles {
  articles: allPrismicArticle {
    nodes {
      data {
        title {
          text
        }
        image {
          url
        }
        paragraph {
          html
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you've found out, there's no difference at all. `nodes` can be thought of as a shortcut to `edges.map(edge => edge.node)`. This'll save us a bit of typing when using the data returned by graphql.

There's a few case where querying edges is useful, for example in a `allMarkdownRemark` query, `edges` may contain helpful info like total posts.